# llc: LLVM ERROR: Cannot select:

Tags: llvm

The `llc` gave me the following error:

`LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: t20: i8,ch = load<LD1[%x], zext from i1> t0, FrameIndex:i16<0>, undef:i16
  t1: i16 = FrameIndex<0>
  t3: i16 = undef
In function: main`

This is the content of the `prg.ll` file:

```
; ModuleID = 'new_module'

define i16 @main() {
entry:
  %x = alloca i1
  store i1 true, i1* %x
  %0 = load i1, i1* %x
  %relation_op = icmp eq i1 %0, true
  br i1 %relation_op, label %then, label %else

then:                                             ; preds = %entry
  store i1 false, i1* %x
  br label %ifcont3

else:                                             ; preds = %entry
  %1 = load i1, i1* %x
  %relation_op1 = icmp eq i1 %1, false
  br i1 %relation_op1, label %then2, label %ifcont

then2:                                            ; preds = %else
  store i1 true, i1* %x
  br label %ifcont

ifcont:                                           ; preds = %then2, %else
  br label %ifcont3

ifcont3:                                          ; preds = %ifcont, %then
  ret i16 0
}
```

I can not understand what the `llc` says. The `prg.ll` output is from my `avr` custom compiler. I found the LLVM-backend for the `avr` at this link: [avr-llvm backend](http://github.com/avr-llvm/llvm). Until now, the backend works fine. Does someone see what is the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider opening an issue in that github repo?

Comment: Yes. I want to be sure that my frontend produces the correct `.ll` file. The `.ll` file is maybe malformed. I can't understand the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed bool type width in my compiler from i1 to i8 (in this case, x is bool). That solved my problem. The avr-backend probably doesn't support i1 or whatever. I will post the answer from the issue tracker if they answer me what's the problem exactly.

---

The answer from issue tracker:

> A bunch of the LLVM backends handle i1 badly (which is pretty sad). This is why almost all frontends define bool to be i8.
>
> I would definitely like to fix this though. By the looks of this, it is probably failing on the zext from i1 operation. All that should be needed is to promote the i1 to an i8 internally.